# What might be a plausible explanation for the drastic lowering of global temperatures?

Tags: climate, weather, natural-growth

**Question:** What circumstances (theoretical or based on actual past events) could lower the global temperature on Earth or an Earth-like planet to an average of 30℉–40℉ (-1℃–4℃)?

Conditions:

- Both natrual and man-made solutions are acceptable.
- The cooling transition may take up to 2,000 years.
- The "ice age" or final cooled condition would last 500–700 years.

The best answer:

- Uses the least amount of magic.
- Causes the least amount of damage to current life on Earth.

*I understand that some extinction or endangerment is inevitable.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A period of solar inactivity. There are less sun spots and solar flares and the output of the sun drops enough to cause a cooling effect on the Earth.

It's believed to be the cause of the ice ages throughout history.

[Solar Inactivity](http://www.icr.org/article/will-solar-inactivity-lead-global-cooling/)

[Diminishing solar activity may bring new Ice Age by 2030](https://astronomynow.com/2015/07/17/diminishing-solar-activity-may-bring-new-ice-age-by-2030/)

Answer (score 2):

**Nazi Necromancers summon an Avatar of Ymir**

The allies are closing in and Hitler pulls out all the stops, looking for victory in the occult. Whether or not this thing is actually Ymir, a personification of the collective will of the Aryan people, an esoteric thought form or just an opportunistic demonic being - they pull something through.

And of course, he is about as disinterested in the Nazi cause as you can imagine. He starts the never-ending Fimbulwinter and begins spawning a race of frost giants to inherit the earth.

Comment: Reviewers!  This is in the low-quality queue.  Please understand that this was posted in response to the OP's original question.  It was a perfectly reasonable (and fairly creative, it'd make a good B-movie) answer back then.  Please bear this in mind as you complete your reviews.  Past answerers are not notified of question edits.